# Advanced item search in combobox C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I wrote a program with C #
I have a combo box whose items are Binding from the database.I use AutoCompleteMode and AutoCompleteSource to search the combo box.But only when filtering does it find words whose first letter is the same as the input letter.While I need All items that contain these letters displayed.Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Share your Code. Front and Backend :)

Comment: Which AutoCompleteMode  used ?

Comment: `code`   comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

Comment: Don't post code in comments, especially unformatted. Edit your question and add the code that you should have added in the first place. That said, what you describe is the way the inbuilt autocomplete works so what you want is not possible without creating your own custom functionality.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps

```
// Example data 
string[] data = new string[] {
    "Absecon","Abstracta","Abundantia","Academia","Acadiau","Acamas",
    "Ackerman","Ackley","Ackworth","Acomita","Aconcagua","Acton","Acushnet",
    "Acworth","Ada","Ada","Adair","Adairs","Adair","Adak","Adalberta","Adamkrafft",
    "Adams"

};
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleTextChanged();
}

// Handle Text Box that you Fill
private void HandleTextChanged()
{
    var txt = comboBox1.Text;
    var list = from d in data
               where d.Tolower().Contains(comboBox1.Text.ToLower())
               select d;
    if (list.Count() > 0)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = list.ToList();
        //comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        var sText = comboBox1.Items[0].ToString();
        comboBox1.SelectionStart = txt.Length;
        comboBox1.SelectionLength = sText.Length - txt.Length;
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = false;
        comboBox1.SelectionStart = txt.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).